# How to remove namespace from child tag

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a requirement where i need to transform my xml.

This is the xml given to me

```
<InvoiceDocument>
<Invoice>
<d>100</d>
<a>120</a>
<Products>
<Product>
<b>11</b>
<c>12</c>
</Product>
<Product>
<b>13</b>
<c>14</c>
</Product>
</Products>
</Invoice>
</InvoiceDocument>
```

This is the xml that i require

```
<MessageParts xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/LedgerGeneralJournal">
<LedgerJournalTable class="entity">
<r:z>50</r:z>
<LedgerJournalTrans class="entity">
<r:e>120</r:e>
</LedgerJournalTrans>
<LedgerJournalTrans class="entity">
<r:g>11</r:g>
<r:h>12</r:h>
</LedgerJournalTrans>
<LedgerJournalTrans class="entity">
<r:g>13</r:g>
<r:h>14</r:h>
</LedgerJournalTrans>
</LedgerJournalTable>
</MessageParts>
```

I tried to use this code for transforming my xml, I was able to transform most of the xml just was getting xmlns="" in each

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:r="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/LedgerGeneralJournal">
  <xsl:template match="InvoiceDocument">
    <MessageParts 
             xmlns:r="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/LedgerGeneralJournal">
      <LedgerJournalTable class="entity">
            <r:z>50</r:z>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Invoice"/>
            </LedgerJournalTable>
            </MessageParts>
          </xsl:template>

          <xsl:template match="Invoice">
          <LedgerJournalTrans class="entity'>
          <r:e><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(a/text()[1])"/></r:e>
          </LedgerJournalTrans>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Products"/>
          </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Products">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Product"/>
  </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="Product">
    <LedgerJournalTrans class="entity'>
    <g><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(b/text()[1])"/></g>
    <h><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(c/text()[1])"/></h>
    </LedgerJournalTrans>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output i am getting after applying this xlst is this, there is xmlns="" in the

```
<MessageParts xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/LedgerGeneralJournal">
<LedgerJournalTable class="entity">
<r:z>50</r:z>
<LedgerJournalTrans class="entity" xmlns="">
<r:e>120</r:e>
</LedgerJournalTrans>
<LedgerJournalTrans class="entity" xmlns="">
<r:g>11</r:g>
<r:h>12</r:h>
</LedgerJournalTrans>
<LedgerJournalTrans class="entity"  xmlns="">
<r:g>13</r:g>
<r:h>14</r:h>
</LedgerJournalTrans>
</LedgerJournalTable>
</MessageParts>
```

So can you help me to remove this xmlns=""

Comment: None of your children does have any namespace.

Comment: So you don't want to remove a namespace, but rather add one?

Comment: Try using `<xsl:element name="MessageParts" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/LedgerGeneralJournal">...</xsl:element>` instead of `<MessageParts xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/LedgerGeneralJournal">`.

Comment: The output that you show is not a well-formed XML document. You cannot use a prefix without binding it to a namespace first. There is no XSL transformation that will produce such result.

Comment: Actually i was unable to post the whole question yesterday and apologies for that. I have now uploaded the whole question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because (1) the provided stylesheet has errors and (2) after fixing those errors it does not produce the claimed result: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1Q1xR and (3) the requested output is not well-formed XML and cannot be produced by XSL transformation.